# Spinning a wheel with two rods

Tags: rotation, centripetal-force

This is more of an engineering question, but I am trying to use two rods to spin a wheel.

```
  A      B
<---- ---->
     O
```

Line A and Line B are pulled in opposite directions
"O" represents a spinning body such as a disc

I'm having trouble conceptualizing a way to use both inputs to spin disc "O"

One idea I had was to use an asymmetric cross to apply force to a central ring which had 'teeth' pushing the disc in one direction on its axis.

Is there a better.. more eloquent (simple?) way?

Comment: What points are the rods connected to on the disc? Are they colinear with the centre of the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, put teeth on the outer edge of your disk and along each rod. Then apply one rod to one side of the disk and the other to the opposite side.

Comment: This is a good idea. I realize that I didn't stipulate the most important bit, the rods will be connected to fixed points and will be applying different loads to the disc to make it spin,.

Comment: If the rods are fixed, then they can't move and neither will the disk (unless the rods form a slope down which the disk can roll).

Comment: I'm going to re-do this with a better picture. I am failing at explaining it.